# WordPress очистка emoji перед записью в базу

Tags: wordpress

Как WordPress преобразует emoji в тексте в код emoji при записи в базу и как он их конвертирует назад?

То есть в тексте они выводятся и хранятся как `<img src ...`, а в базе они хранятся как код ....

Какие именно функции это делают в WordPress . Мне нужно для того, чтобы при сохранении очищать правильно текстовое поле и потом при повторном выводе (или отправки на email) эти emoji должны правильно отображаться.

Comment: ?? от чего очищать? и зачем отчищать от emoji, что бы их потом выводить (откуда брать?)?  И зачем вообще думать о функциях ВП в данном случае - ВП сам всё выведет если смайлы будут в тексте.

Answer (score 1):

В базе они хранятся как символы, например `:)`. А вот при выводе форматируются функцией `wp_encode_emoji( $content )` в файле `wp-includes/formatting.php`.

Именно эта функция преобразует их в html-сущности типа

```
<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.4/svg/1f642.svg">
```